# How to find the whether the sprite is collide with the other sprite in cocos2d-android?

Tags: java, android, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-android

I have searched alot in order to make the sprite(_player) detected and collide with the other sprite(target) and being removed after the collision through out google and stackoverflow site, but could not get the solution in cocos2d-android, i'm able to find lots of information on cocos2d-iphone not on android, even i have compared my code with iphone code but could not make out.
this is how i had done.

```
public class GameLayer extends CCColorLayer
 {
protected LinkedList<CCSprite> _targets;
protected LinkedList<CCSprite> _projectiles;
protected int _projectilesDestroyed;
protected CCSprite _player;
protected CCSprite _nextProjectile;

public static CCScene scene()
{
    CCScene scene = CCScene.node();
    CCColorLayer layer = new GameLayer(ccColor4B.ccc4(255, 255, 255, 255));

    scene.addChild(layer);

    return scene;
}


protected GameLayer(ccColor4B color)
{
    super(color);

    this.setIsTouchEnabled(true);

    _targets = new LinkedList<CCSprite>();
    _projectiles = new LinkedList<CCSprite>();
    _projectilesDestroyed = 0;

    CGSize winSize = CCDirector.sharedDirector().displaySize();

    _player = CCSprite.sprite("Player2.png");
    _player.setPosition(CGPoint.ccp(_player.getContentSize().width / 2.0f, winSize.height / 2.0f));

    addChild(_player);


    this.schedule("gameLogic", 1.0f);
    this.schedule("update");
}
```

update method

```
public void update(float dt)
{
    LinkedList<CCSprite> projectilesToDelete = new LinkedList<CCSprite>();

    for (CCSprite projectile : _projectiles)
    {
        CGRect projectileRect = CGRect.make(projectile.getPosition().x - (projectile.getContentSize().width / 2.0f),
                                            projectile.getPosition().y - (projectile.getContentSize().height / 2.0f),
                                            projectile.getContentSize().width,
                                            projectile.getContentSize().height);

        LinkedList<CCSprite> targetsToDelete = new LinkedList<CCSprite>();

        for (CCSprite target : _targets)
        {
            CGRect targetRect = CGRect.make(target.getPosition().x - (target.getContentSize().width),
                                            target.getPosition().y - (target.getContentSize().height),
                                            target.getContentSize().width,
                                            target.getContentSize().height);



            _player = CCSprite.sprite("Player2.png");
            _player.setPosition(CGPoint.ccp(50,100));
            CGRect playerRect = CGRect.make(_player.getPosition().x - (_player.getContentSize().width / 2.0f),
                    _player.getPosition().y - (_player.getContentSize().height / 2.0f),
                    _player.getContentSize().width,
                    _player.getContentSize().height);

            if (CGRect.intersects(projectileRect, targetRect))
                targetsToDelete.add(target);


            else if (CGRect.intersects(playerRect, targetRect))
                _player.remove(_player);
            removeChild(_player, true);

        }

        for (CCSprite target : targetsToDelete)
        {
            _targets.remove(target);
            removeChild(target, true);
        }

        if (targetsToDelete.size() > 0)
            projectilesToDelete.add(projectile);
    }
```

Comment: Are you using Dan Clarke example or else ?

Comment: yes i'm using that tutorial only @user2078315

Comment: So, the  code is working fine when the two sprite collides. What error u got ?

Comment: i'm not getting any error, the sprites are crossing each other but not getting collided and delete @user2078315

Comment: I have also download the code ... And works fine in my case ..  I'll check it again with ur code and ASAP ...

Comment: there is not problem in the downloaded code it works fine, but i have added seperate ship sprite with cannon, when the fireball falls on the ship, ship is not deleted@user2078315

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find out the solution for this answer it took a week:( When a new sprite is added in the game first it should be declared in addsomefunction() method, my mistake was i declared the value of ship(sprite) in constructor not in the addTarget() and to remove the sprite after collision the code has to be given in `public void spriteMoveFinished(Object sender)` as

```
if (sprite.getTag() == 25)
_ships.remove(sprite);
```

since i had Target(sprite) in this method got confused like where to add the code.